# Installing Pyramid without the template systems (Mako and Chameleon)

Tags: python, pyramid

Is there a "good way" to **install Pyramid without the templating systems**? The templating systems I speak of are Mako and Chameleon. **In Single Page Applications (SPA) there is very little need for server-side templating** since all of the templates are rendered on the client-side with javascript. I like the power of Pyramid but the template system is unnecessary baggage in some cases.

I have a feeling that the only way to accomplish this task is to fork Pyramid and modify the setup.py to remove these dependencies. That may break things,but then again, Pyramid is built in such a way that it may not care as long as nothing tries to call a renderer for one of these templates. Who knows?

Comment: I think you'd be best off sticking with normal Pyramid, not calling any render actions ( except for JSON ) and not worrying about the rest. 

I don't believe that Pyramid loads any templating libraries unless you try to render something with a given extension - however the error screens and debug tools are all template driven. You're likely to seriously break things if you fork.

Honestly, the various libraries you're talking about are barely any baggage at all.  The way you structured the question, your concerns seem like a lot more premature optimization than addressing a tangible problem.

Comment: I agree with you, but my client and their ops people don't like the idea of having unused packages/libraries on the system. Since this is a deployment issue rather than a development issue, yes, it is likely a premature optimization. However, this optimization has affected the choice of framework. I'm only trying to get some idea how to resolve this concern from any future client that raises the same question. So while it might not be a tangible computer science problem, it is a real problem that effects some project outcomes. And in this case the outcome has been to not use Pyramid.

Answer (score 2):

There is a project to eventually remove those templating dependancies and make them available as separate packages. The work started at last year pycon sprints and can be continued this year, who knows. OTOH having those packages installed in your venv doesn't really affect your app so just avoid using them and only use the JSON renderer or any other renderers. Instead of forking Pyramid and removing those dependancies in setup.py I propose you to join us and work on the removal project so we can all benefit the same features.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive response. This is very helpful. I likely will join this effort.

Comment: If you're attending pycon this year, join us at the pyramid sprint.